# Different cross chaincode behavior for two different chaincode methods

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, chaincode

I am invoking a cross chaincode from the **set** method of my chaindode and it properly records the information I send. However, when I invoke the cross chaincode from the **get** method, then the data is not recorded.

To verify that it was not an implementation failure, I copied the function that goes in the **get** method into the **set** method as a test and it responded correctly, so I suspect that it is the fact of invoking the same cross-chaincode from another method.

Part of the **set** method code that works properly including the function copied from **get** method:

```
log.SetFlags(0)
uuid = uuidgen()
TxID = stub.GetTxID()
timestamp = timeNow()
log.Println("["+timestamp+"]["+uuid+"]["+CHANNEL_ENV+"]["+TxID+"][usecase_cc][Transaction] Transaction makes payment of X units from A to B")
re = captureOutput(func(){
    log.Println("["+timestamp+"]["+uuid+"]["+CHANNEL_ENV+"]["+TxID+"][usecase_cc][Transaction] Transaction makes payment of X units from A to B")
})
invokeArgs = prepareToInvoke(uuid, re)
stub.InvokeChaincode("base_cc", invokeArgs, CHANNEL_ENV)

//IMPORTED FROM GET METHOD
Avalbytes, err = stub.GetState(A) // Get the state from the ledger
log.SetFlags(0)
uuid = uuidgen()
TxID = stub.GetTxID()
timestamp = timeNow()
jsonResp := "{\"Name\":\"" + A + "\",\"Amount\":\"" + string(Avalbytes) + "\"}"
log.Println("["+timestamp+"]["+uuid+"]["+CHANNEL_ENV+"]["+TxID+"][Get] Query Response: "+jsonResp)
re = captureOutput(func(){
    log.Println("["+timestamp+"]["+uuid+"]["+CHANNEL_ENV+"]["+TxID+"][Get] Query Response: "+jsonResp)
})
invokeArgs = prepareToInvoke(uuid, re)
stub.InvokeChaincode("base_cc", invokeArgs, CHANNEL_ENV)
//IMPORTED FROM GET METHOD
```

The failure is that when querying the cross chaincode it returns that the asset has not been inserted. The first four logs have been inserted from the **set** method and the last one that fails has been tried to insert from the **get** method:

```
response 3zjRkx5KXL65KPn4XGc9SjgWBRVS07i07ecWTMmCRf8=
response A+Mq4UjLrvTRyVXEgBsgA5Pvk2WTUjKYa0NYKxMwtG0=
response vlstiHrCz2tw3t8Ba4C9GbHo/nYrVwstP8JnEPhRAJc=
response KYE+acbDesekYslXT87EEZ546eVSIUREJlHI+8f8ZNY=

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "query.py", line 91, in <module>
response = loop.run_until_complete(cli.chaincode_query(
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fabric_sdk_py-0.9.0-py3.8.egg/hfc/fabric/client.py", 
line 1328, in chaincode_query
return await chaincode.query(requestor, channel_name, peers, args,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fabric_sdk_py-0.9.0-py3.8.egg/hfc/fabric/chaincode.py", 
line 316, in query
raise Exception(res)
Exception: [response {
status: 500
message: "Asset not found: 3280ca60-0352-40c4-83ab-b9c8e25d0f1f"
```

To clarify the error, I have created this image where:
[Cross-Chaincode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gsYo.png)

**1A**) Invoke the transaction (usecase chaincode) via Python SDK and set the method to add the peer (A, Aval) in the blockchain.

**2A**) Add the peer (A, Aval) through the put state API (usecase chaincode). This action generates a log.

**3A**) Collect the log on-chain and send it to another chaincode through a cross-chain invocation (from the usecase chaincode to the base chaincode).

**4A**) Add the pair (logUUID, base64(sha256(log(SET(A)))) through the put state API (Base Chaincode).

**5A**) Query the use case chaincode via the get method to retrieve Aval from A.

**6A**) Query Aval of A through the get state API in usecase chaincode. This action generates a new record.

**7A**) Collect the log in chaincode and send it to another chaincode via cross chaincode invocation.

**8A**) Adds the pair (logUUID, base64(sha256(log(GET(A)))) via the put state API (chaincode base).

**1B**) Query base chaincode via get method to retrieve base64(sha256(log(SET(A))).

**2B**) Retrieve base64(sha256(log(SET(A))) from logUUID via get state API in chaincode base.

**3B**) Query base chaincode via get method to retrieve base64(sha256(log(GET(A)))).

**4B**) Retrieve base64(sha256(log(GET(A))) from logUUID via get state API in chaincode base (**Here happens the error**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was produced by Python SDK function chaincode_query.

I have oppened an issue in the Hyperledger Fabric Python SDK. However, to solve the issue I am using chaincode_invoke instead of chaincode_query.

[chaincode_invoke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zmks.png)

Now, I can generate and retrieve logs from [get] method.

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Takzz.png)

... and also verify it:

[base64 of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuTTQ.png)